# Are there easy way to call webhooks from iOS share extension?

Tags: ios, webhooks

Yeah I know I can create my own iOS app with share extension that post data to any url, but are there any already?

- Zapier has [outgoing webhook integration](https://zapier.com/apps/webhook/integrations), but no [iOS app yet](https://zapier.com/apps/iphone/integrations).
- [Pushbullet doesn't seems to have outgoing webhook](https://docs.pushbullet.com/)
- I don' know ifttt has outgoing webhook.

Comment: You would need to write an app with your own share extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [workflow.is](https://workflow.is/) to make calls to any URL. [Frederico Viticci wrote a detailed post here](https://www.macstories.net/ios/workflow-update-brings-ability-to-interact-with-any-web-api/) on how to interact with APIs. This should work for just making a call to a webhook URL as well.

Here is the documentation on how to make any workflow availble from the share extension: https://workflow.is/docs/using-workflows-from-the-action-extension

Comment: what you are trying to ask?

Comment: Thanks. with Workflow.is I can post url to any url.